# Customizing X-Axis Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am currently facing a problem regarding customizing the x-Axis in a Python plot I made. 
I have the following plot:
[image]

And this is the respective Python Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/lukaskoston/Desktop/MasterarbeitFOMCAnalysis/02_Cleaning Process/Wordcount Raw.csv", delimiter=";")
print(df.head)
print(df.info)
x = df['Date'].values
y = df['Wordcount'].values

plt.title("Size of FOMC statements measured in total used words")
plt.ylabel("Amount of words")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.plot(np.array(x) / 1000, y)
plt.show()
```

The Data looks as follows (example), total observations = 170, for the range from 1999 to 2019.

[image]

**My question**: I would like to customize the x-Axis, so that it ranges from 1999 to 2019.
I was not able to do this...

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `import numpy as np; plt.plot(np.array(x) / 1000, y)`

Comment: I updated the post, as the x axis looks not as I expected... Do you have an idea? Thanks anyway!

Comment: What do the last 3 digits of your Date column mean? They are ordered quite strange

Comment: Sorry, was not everything captured in the column.... it is a date format (yyyymmdd)

Answer (score 0):

If the x-column is in the format 'YYYYMMDD', and there aren't too many dates per year, you can get a good approximation of numeric dates with:

- separate the year as `x // 10000`
- separate the month as `(x % 10000) // 100`
- separate the day as `x % 100`
- subtract 1 from month and day
- add `1/31`th of the day to the month, divide everything by 12 and add to the year

This will leave a very small gap for the months that don't have 31 days, but that would be insignificant when there are only a few dates per year.

In code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

# first create some random toy data
x = np.sort(np.random.randint(1999, 2020, 170) * 10000 + np.random.randint(1, 13, 170) * 100 + np.random.randint(1, 29, 170))
y = np.random.randint(150, 400, 170)

# convert the x-array to numerical dates in year units:
x = np.array(x)
dates = x // 10000 + ((x % 10000) // 100 - 1 + (x % 100 - 1) / 31) / 12

# create a line plot
plt.plot(dates, y)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1)) # one tick per year
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question?